# Printing by Mr. Maty Hall.: How do i code if the print is successfull?

Tags: java

This is the code where a form can be printed. Created by Marty Hall. I just wanted to ask if maybe I can code whenever I click the "OK" button in the printing form where you set the properties of the form that you will print and how do i do it? in what part of this code? sorry if i cant make myself clear. XD

```
package thesis;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

/** A simple utility class that lets you very simply print
 *  an arbitrary component. Just pass the component to the
 *  PrintUtilities.printComponent. The component you want to
 *  print doesn't need a print method and doesn't have to
 *  implement any interface or do anything special at all.
 *  <P>
 *  If you are going to be printing many times, it is marginally more
 *  efficient to first do the following:
 *  <PRE>
 *    PrintUtilities printHelper = new PrintUtilities(theComponent);
 *  </PRE>
 *  then later do printHelper.print(). But this is a very tiny
 *  difference, so in most cases just do the simpler
 *  PrintUtilities.printComponent(componentToBePrinted).
 *
 *  7/99 Marty Hall, http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/
 *  May be freely used or adapted.
 */

public class PrintUtilities implements Printable {
  private Component componentToBePrinted;

  public static void printComponent(Component c) {
    new PrintUtilities(c).print();
  }

  public PrintUtilities(Component componentToBePrinted) {
    this.componentToBePrinted = componentToBePrinted;
  }

  public void print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog())
      try {
        printJob.print();
      } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
      }
  }

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex > 0) {
      return(NO_SUCH_PAGE);
    } else {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
      disableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      componentToBePrinted.paint(g2d);
      enableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      return(PAGE_EXISTS);
    }
  }

  /** The speed and quality of printing suffers dramatically if
   *  any of the containers have double buffering turned on.
   *  So this turns if off globally.
   *  @see enableDoubleBuffering
   */
  public static void disableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);
  }

  /** Re-enables double buffering globally. */

  public static void enableDoubleBuffering(Component c) {
    RepaintManager currentManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(c);
    currentManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code can't all be relevant. You also failed to describe your problem and pose a question.

Comment: Pasting part of a book and aiming for us to understand an out-of-context question is rather rude. Please elaborate your question a little further so we can trully understand you.

Comment: i edited it. sorry. but in the whole code i cant seem to find the part where i can code the OK button or the CANCEL button

Comment: *I can code whenever I click the "OK" button in the printing form where you set the properties of the form that you will print* ... Yes you can...

Comment: What do you mean by "code whenever I click the OK button"? I don't entirely understand this part.

Comment: there is a form that i want to print and by just typing this `PrintUtilities.printComponent(myform);`, a printing property form pops up and lets the user choose to continue to print the form or cancel the operation. I need to determine if the user clicked either the OK or the CANCEL button

Comment: Have you bothered to read **any** tutorial at all? Voting to close.

Comment: i have. sorry if you dont understand the question. ill be deleting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog())
      try {
          System.out.println("code here");
        printJob.print();
      } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
      }
  }
```

i found it. sorry for posting this. i cant delete the question because it says that it has answers by others. And I figured out that here is the part where i can code.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your question. The difficulty you are having is because the PrintUtilities class does not expose whether or not the use decided to print or cancel the operation. If you would like it to do that you need to make a few modifications:

```
public static Boolean printComponent(Component c) {
    return (new PrintUtilities(c)).print();
}

public Boolean print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog()) { // i assume this is where the dialog is shown
        // user decided to print
        try {
            printJob.print();
        } catch(PrinterException pe) {
            System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // user canceled
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when you call printComponent it will return whether or not it was actually printed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach an `ActionListner` to you "print" button

```
btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      PrintUtilities pu = new PrintUtilities(componentToBePrinted);
      pu.print();
    }
}
```

You might to have a read through [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more information